# Nivo slider: trying to increase rotation speed

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm working on a site that uses the nivo slider. It's working fine...just the images don't move fast enough. I read the documentation, and made the following changes in the jquery.nivo.slider.js file:

```
animSpeed: 1000,
pauseTime: 1000,
```

to
     animSpeed: 10,
     pauseTime: 50,

My problem? I can't get the sliders to auto-rotate at all!

Can someone give me any pointers?

http://dev.htnbank.com

Using jQuery 1.9.1. Other than the speed being...well, not moving, the nivo slider works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you have this in your js file called `main` (lines 59-64):

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({ 
    effect: 'fade',  
    pauseTime: 3000000, // <- this is causing your problems
    directionNav: true, 
    customChange: function(){Cufon.replace('.nivo-caption');}
});
```

The `pauseTime` option is making the slide wait 50 minutes in between each slide. You've changed the nivoSlider default settings in `jquery.nivo.slider.js` but the options from the code above are overwriting it. This is what you should change it to:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({ 
    effect: 'fade',
    animSpeed: 500,
    pauseTime: 500,
    directionNav: true, 
    customChange: function(){Cufon.replace('.nivo-caption');}
});
```

I used `500ms` for both options as the values you wanted to use would make the slides move so fast that no one would be able to view them.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#slider').nivoSlider({
          effect: 'fade',
          animSpeed: 340,
          pauseTime: 6000    
     });
});
```